# Proof that if $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c>0$ then $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+2b}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b+2c}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+2a}}<\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Proof that if $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c>0$ then $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+2b}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{b+2c}} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{c+2a}}<\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}$

Edit: I tried using the cauchy schwarz inequality and all I need to prove is this inequality to solve the problem presented above.
[image]

In other words, if I can prove that: [image]

The problem is solved, thank you so much in advanced, this means so much to me.

Comment: mathSE reviewers are hoping that you will edit your query to show what you have tried.  It doesn't matter whether your attempts succeeded.  Please show as much of your work as you can.

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1425385p8028997

Comment: Hello @MartinR , this is so helpful but I don´t understand why the inequality whith the 1/2 at the end is True, it is not proved in the solution, I posted the image of the inequality in an edit I made, if you could help me I would appreciate so much, thank you very much

Comment: That is simply because $\frac{a}{a+2b} < \frac{a}{a+b}$ .